# How do I change the subsection by Roman letter to number in Lyx?

Tags: sectioning, templates, lyx-layouts

I am using one IEEE template to write one two column paper,
after converted into pdf format, the subsection is identified with Roman letters, such as 
I, II, III, IV, etc. I want to change it to numbers like: 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does adding the command `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}` to your document preamble solve this problem?

Comment: In Lyx you can access the preamble from menu: Document > Document Settings > LaTeX Preamble.

Comment: it still shows Roman letters

Comment: @Mike: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Remember, keep it *minimal*, so just include your `\documentclass`, the required packages, and some sectional headings, so we can see your Roman subsection letters.

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, [the `IEEEtran` class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/) defaults to upper case Roman numerals for `sections` and upper case letters for `subsections`, and adding `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}` seems to have no effect.

However, there is a `[compsoc]` class option that is intended to mimic the format of the IEEE Computer Society's publications, and one those adjustments that is made with this is that Arabic numerals are used exclusively for `sections` and `subsections`. So the following MWE produces the desired results:

[image]

```
\documentclass[compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\section{Section One}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\end{document}
```

There are other things that this option effects so is best to refer to the package documentation.

Answer (score 4):

The **IEEEtran** class numbers *sections* with Roman numbers and *subsections* with letters.

So the correct remedy is

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

Comment: This seems to work for `\section` but not `\subsection` as per the OP.

Comment: @PeterGrill The subsections are *not* numbered with Roman numbers as the OP says.

Answer (score 3):

Looking through the IEEEtrans.cls file, you'll see that they use:

`\def\thesectiondis{\thesection.}                   % I.`

`\def\thesubsectiondis{\Alph{subsection}.}          % B.` 
`\def\thesubsubsectiondis{\arabic{subsubsection})}  % 3)` 
`\def\theparagraphdis{\alph{paragraph})}            % d)`

for non comsoc papers. To change the section numbering simply redefine the above four lines according to you requirements. For example, if you want full arabic separated by full stops (as is the case for comsoc) then use:

`\def\thesectiondis{\thesection.}`
`\def\thesubsectiondis{\thesectiondis\arabic{subsection}.}`
`\def\thesubsubsectiondis{\thesubsectiondis\arabic{subsubsection}.}`
`\def\theparagraphdis{\thesubsubsectiondis\arabic{paragraph}.}`

Comment: I just realised that this has already been answered  [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125254/42367).