# Section numbering changes in TOC, but not in body - specific to IEEEtran

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, ieeetran

I'm having a strange issue with the IEEEtran package. I'm using `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}` and so on to change the section, subsection, and subsubsection numbering. As mentioned in the title, I see the changes in the TOC, but not in the body of the document. MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
Words, words, all words

\section{Big section}

\subsection{Section Three}

\subsubsection{SubSection Three}~\\ texty text

\subsubsection{title}~\\ texty text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An IEEE journal paper is not supposed to have a ToC. So it's protecting its headings but not caring about the ToC.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that I'm mangling the IEEE journal format a bit - it's actually for a university report, and they want IEEE guidelines to be followed in some areas (e.g. the bibliography/reference formats/figure caption locations), but not all (they'd still like a TOC)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change the numbering of the main text headings (as opposed to those used in the ToC), you have to redefine `\thesectiondis`, `\thesubsectiondis`, and `\thesubsubsectiondis`.

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\renewcommand\thesectiondis{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsectiondis{\thesectiondis.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsectiondis{\thesubsectiondis.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
Words, words, all words

\section{Big section}

\subsection{Section Three}

\subsubsection{SubSection Three}~\\ texty text

\subsubsection{title}~\\ texty text

\end{document}
```

[image]